# Escaping closures on the runtime stack?

Tags: swift, closures, callstack, activation-record

How are Swift’s closures implemented on the runtime stack? I imagine non-escaping closures are just sent with an extra access link to the stack frame it encloses, but how do escaping closures work? Where is its enclosed activation record maintained?

Comment: escaping closures with captured variables are stored as memory managed boxes on the heap (using ARC). In fact, all closures start like this, until the optimizer does a pass which promotes it to the stack, when possible to do so.

Comment: @Alexander , if the variables live in the heap, how are they accessed by the original function they live in? Or does Swift automatically convert every variable that lives a function that contains a closure to heap variables?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41256612/how-are-escaping-closures-implemented-in-swift-3-under-the-hood-are-they-impl

Comment: @taylorswift Yep, the local variables are moved to the heap whenever there's a closure that will need to capture them and box them on the heap, so that they can outlive the stack frame of the function they were allocated in

Comment: See e.g. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/308/ at around the 37 minute mark

Comment: Also https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/712/ at 23:22

Comment: Also relevant: [Swift function object wrapper in apple/swift](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43171341/2976878)